# Left derived functor on a short exact sequence

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, homology-cohomology, homological-algebra

**Question:**

The i'th left derived functor $L_iF$ of an additive functor $F:\mathcal{A\to B}$ is defined to be $H_iFP$,where $P$ is taking the projective resolution of $A$(and drop $A$),$F$ acts degreewise and $H_i$ taking the i'th homology.

If we have a short exact sequence $0\to A\to B\to C\to 0$ in $\mathcal{A}$,then $0\to P(A)\to P(B)\to P(C)\to 0$ is split exact in $\mathcal{K_{\geqslant 0}(Proj(A))}$,which denotes the homotopy category of projectives in $\mathcal{A}$.

Since $F$ is additive,it preserves split exact(degreewise).So $0\to FP(A)\to FP(B)\to FP(C)\to 0$ is split exact.

The above works well,but I've got trouble with the following process:

1)Since $0\to FP(A)\to FP(B)\to FP(C)\to 0$ is exact,we apply the homology long exact sequence theorem and get a long exact sequence:$...\to H_i(A)\to H_i(B)\to H_i(C)\to H_{i-1}(A)\to ...$

2)But we know that $H_i$ is an additive functor from $\mathcal{Ch(A)}$ to $\mathcal{A}$,so it preserves direct sum of complexes,which is defined degreewise.Therefore,$H_i(B)\simeq H_i(A\oplus C)\simeq H_i(A)\oplus H_i(C)$,but this will force $H_{i-1}(A)=0$(or to say we will get a short exact sequence for each $H_i$),a contradiction to 1).

I wonder which step fails in 2).Thanks in advance!

Comment: The short exact sequences of resolutions is *degreewise* split, but not split as a short exact sequence of complexes

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez I see...so the collection of the degreewise iso does not form an iso for complexes.

Comment: Just try it. You do not have to trust me. Unless you actually try to prove they do make an iso of complexes and see why they do not, you will not have a actually understood this. Don't let anyone rob you of the moment in which you see what breaks.

Comment: The morphism $d:P_{i+1}(A)\oplus P_{i+1}(C)\to P_{i}(A)\oplus P_{i}(C)$ determined in the Horseshoe lemma is something like $\left(\begin{matrix}d'&*\\0&d''\end{matrix}\right)$,but $d=\left(\begin{matrix}d'&0\\0&d''\end{matrix}\right)$ in $P(A)\oplus P(C)$,so we can't build an iso from $P(B)$ to $P(A)\oplus P(C)$.

Comment: Indeed. Notice that *sometimes* the sequence does split, even if you construct d in the horseshoe lemma with the bad luck that the * is non zero — the splitting is not the obvious candidate, in those cases. Do you have an actual example in which there is no splitting at all?

Comment: (A good exercise is to see what happens when there *is* a splitting compatible with the differentials in one degree. This has to be related somehow with the connecting morphism, as you noted, but how exactly?)

Comment: Consider the exact sequence $0\to\mathbb{Z\to Z\to Z/nZ\to 0}$.Take $\to 0\to\mathbb{Z\to Z\to 0}$ as the resolution for $\mathbb Z$,and $\to 0\to \mathbb{Z\to Z\to Z/nZ\to 0}$for $\mathbb{Z/nZ}$,construct the resolution for the middle by Horseshoe lemma and we get $0\to\mathbb{Z\to Z\oplus Z\to Z\to 0}$ for the 0th,$0\to 0\to\mathbb{Z\to Z\to 0}$ for the 1st.The connecting morphism for the middle is $(1,n):\mathbb{Z\to Z\oplus Z}$,hence it does not split,as the morphisms besides are $0,n$.

Comment: If we just take a random resolution for the middle and require it to be split($h_i:P_i(B)\to P_i(A)\oplus P_i(C)$ is an iso),then we may conclude that $(d^A_i\oplus d^C_i)h_i=h_{i-1}d^B_i$?

Comment: I think that example works.

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Comment: @shdvt Please consider writing that counterexample as an answer to your own post.